# How can I check in a jest test if a thunk action within a thunk action creator has been dispatched?

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

Here's a generalized example:

```js
// myActions.js
export const actionOne = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actionTwo());
};

export const actionTwo = () => ({
    type: 'SOME_TYPE',
});
```

I would like to test that `actionTwo` has been either called or dispatched, ideally without the test knowing anything about what is going on in `actionTwo`, because I have a different test that takes care of that.

I am using `redux-mock-store` to dispatch the tested action to a mocked store and calling `store.getActions()` to find out if the expected actions within the thunk action creator have been dispatched. I feel it is not the right way to go in this particular scenario because then the test would test more than it should. I really only want to know if `actionTwo` has been called at all.

I'm aware of `spyOn` and `jest.mock`, but I've been unable to use either to solve my problem. Here's what the generalized test looks like:

```js
// myActions.test.js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from 'myActions';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

test('actionOne', () => {
    const store = mockStore();

    return store.dispatch(actions.actionOne()).then(() => {
        // TODO: check if actions.actionTwo was called
    });
});

test('actionTwo', () => {
    const store = mockStore();

    return store.dispatch(actions.actionTwo()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: 'SOME_TYPE' }]);
    }); 
});
```

I'm grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while, but I figured it out. It's not ideal (because it involves a small change to the tested code), but the closest to ideal that I could get.

```js
// myActions.js
export const actionOne = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(exports.actionTwo());
};

export const actionTwo = () => ({
    type: 'SOME_TYPE',
});
```

The important change is the `exports.actionTwo()`. That way, I make sure that I can overwrite the function's implementation from the outside (the test file) and the overwriting function will actually be called from within the imported file.

Now I can simply add something like the following to my test file:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    actions.actionTwo = jest.fn(() => () => Promise.resolve());
});
```

`actionTwo` is now being mocked and I can use `toBeCalledWith` and other expectations on it. If I wish to test its actual implementation within the same test file, I can store it in a variable before calling `beforeEach`, like:

```js
const actionTwo = actions.actionTwo;
```

And then in the test setup for its implementation, I can overwrite the mock calling

```js
actions.actionTwo = actionTwo;
```

That's it. Now I can make sure to ignore all side effects from an exported function and test it as an actual unit.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to assert that two **redux actions** hit the store, not that actionOne calls the action creator.

Since all actions dispatched to the store must have an action `type`. Just make assertions about `store.getActions()`:

```
test('actionOne', () => {
    const store = mockStore();
    return store.dispatch(actions.actionOne()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).to.have.length(2);
        expect(store.getActions()[0].type).to.equal('ACTION_ONE_TYPE');
        // make additional assertions about the first action

        expect(store.getActions()[1].type).to.equal('ACTION_TWO_TYPE');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not convinced this is the right way. Imagine `actionTwo` was not a simple action creator but a thunk, dispatching its own actions, possibly even conditionally. I don't want to know about any of that logic in the test for `actionOne`, I just want to make sure that `actionTwo` was dispatched at all or even only that the function was called. Is there no simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Agreed. I don't want to test the implementation of the action (it's tested elsewhere), I just want to test that it was called.